# A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget when using a Provider.of<ProvoiderName>(context)

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I have a question. When using this line of code

```
final String email = Provider.of<Auth>(context).email;
```

Inside my `build` method in my `StatelessWidget` and when I try to execute it/call it like this:

```
child: Text(email),
```

I am getting the following error

> The following assertion was thrown building InitDrawer(dirty, dependencies:
>   I/flutter (17778): [InheritedProvider, MediaQuery]):
>   I/flutter (17778): A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.

But when I use it like this

```
child: Text("${email}"),
```

Can you tell me what is the difference and why I am not getting error when calling it with braces? And is this the right way to code in flutter? I am getting my email with an async method, so I guess that's why I am getting null when first the app is loaded, but in the App itself I can see the email without any errors I only see the error in the Console in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

So the braces are for using the value of a parameter inside a string which is in double quotes. So when the 'email' param doesn't have any value, guess what goes inside the double quotes? Only empty double quotes, which is a valid string. But when you give the param value without braces and double quotes, if the param is null(i.e. in the beginning) then Text(null) gets null. And for the Text widget one parameter- the string is mandatory. Can't take null.
Correct method? Do you want to show a placeholder inside the Text()? Then inside Text() - email??"Placeholder".
Want to keep it empty? Text("$email")

Comment: yeah that makes sense

Comment: Cool right? Acceptable answer above description? :)